# Button does nothing

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to make a button that goes from activity 2 to activity 3.
I already made a button that goes from activity 1 to 2 and that worked perfectly. When I press the button in the app it does nothing. This is my code so far.

This is Main2Activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRemote);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my activity_main2.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="uk.co.ndevr.evewebapp20.Main2Activity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRemote"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="TV Remote"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.082"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="uk.co.ndevr.evewebapp20">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main3Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main3"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Main3Activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main3Activity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception in your logcat?

Comment: is it crashing, or just do nothing,
If crashing please post the logs and if not then post the code of your activity2 xml and manifest

Comment: No it's not crashing at all. It just does nothing.

Comment: And no exception in the logcat

Comment: Please share your activity_main2.xml source

Comment: Is the `clickListener` called at all?

Comment: Can you add also your manifest content?

Comment: Can you see the selection effect on the button when you press it?

Comment: Maybe your Main3Activity called finish()?

Comment: Code looks fine. Set a breakpoint and use the debugger to inspect your variables

Comment: If you want, try putting `android:onClick` in the XML and implement it that way

Comment: Can you share your `Main3Activity` ?

Comment: As I undestood the flow is Activity1->Activity2->Activity3 so if you are running Activity2 from 1 is that starting with any additional flag?

Comment: Can you share the method which is used to start activity 2?

Comment: The method I used to start 2 was way different.

Comment: public void onClickLogin(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        }

Comment: I tried the same for activity 3, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never actually switching to `MainActivity2` in the first `Activity`.

Calling `setContentView()` only changes the layout file inflated for the *current* `Activity`. This means, you have never called `Activity2` so the `onCreate()` of your 2nd `Activity` is never called and the `OnClickListener` for that button is never registered.

In your `onClick()` of your first `Activity`, change from calling `setContentView()` (you almost never want to do this more than once in an `Activity`) to using an `Intent` as you are doing in the second `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

The issse is that, as you've said in the comment, you used

```
public void onClickLogin(View view) { 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); 
}
```

to go from activity 1 to activity 2. That simply changed the layout on activity 1 with the one from activity 2. In other words, you're still in activity 1 (that looks like activity 2), while the onClickListener for `btnRemote` is only defined in activity 2.